# Extjs combobox doesn't work after applying css scale transformation

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I require to scale an app in order to fit it inside and iframe with fixed size but I noticed than extjs 4 combobox list doesn't work scaled, it's the first time I see this problem with scale transformation and I guess it affects all floating components in ext.

Here is an example

> ```
> body {
>   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
>   -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
>   -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
>   -o-transform: scale(0.8);
>   transform: scale(0.8);
> }
>
> //Example from extjs documentation
> Ext.onReady(function(){
>
> // The data store containing the list of states
> var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
>     fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
>     data : [
>         {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
>         {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
>         {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
>         //...
>     ]
> });
>
> // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
> Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
>     fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
>     store: states,
>     queryMode: 'local',
>     displayField: 'name',
>     valueField: 'abbr',
>     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
> });
>     
> });
> ```
>
> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kab3/1/) showing the Issue

And when I try to open the list it doesn't seems to be in the right position.

is there a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in specs and browser implementations, but for webkit and FF at least I've been able to debug this down to the use of [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) by `Ext`. This function returns actual screen sizes (i.e. scaled values in your case), while most others computations are done with pre-scale measures (how to call these? CSS dimensions? dunno...).

The fix that logically comes to mind is to try and replace this method to make it return the unscaled dimensions... Surprisingly, it "works". I put some distance here because what I really know is only that it fixes your fiddle in my version of Chrome and FF, and I can't tell for other browsers (but I've seen some specific treatment for IE in the relevant Ext code), or what it could break elsewhere...

Anyway, you might want to try it on a larger scale and see if everything holds together. Here's the fix (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kab3/4/) -- btw, you've commented out all your CSS, except for webkit):

```
Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = function() {
    var left = this.offsetLeft,
        top = this.offsetTop,
        height = this.offsetHeight,
        width = this.offsetWidth;
    return {
        left: left
        ,top: top
        ,width: width
        ,height: height
        ,right: left + width
        ,bottom: top + height
    };
};
```

Of course, I don't recommend to brutally override the native browser `Element` this way, but that may be enough to test it and realize it won't fit the bill. If it appears it could work on all the platforms you want to support, you may want to try to fix Ext itself instead. Here's a starter...

There is a support flag for this method in Ext: `Ext.supports.BoundingClientRect`. Begin with turning that off.

Now this flag is only tested in one place of Ext (4.2.0), but the method is called 8 other times. Most of them are used to decipher browser capabilities; I can't tell what the impact here is. But I can tell that the last one does matter: it's in [`Ext.Element#getXY`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Element_position.html#Ext-dom-Element-static-method-getXY) static method.